# Install a specific package version

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit

I need to install a `tofrodos 1.17.3` for `i386`. I'm running `Ubuntu 16.04.2` and I know that if I run `sudo apt-get install tofrodos:i386` it will install version `1.17.3`. However this will be in a script which possibly will be used much later and I need to fix the version, `1.17.3` and the 32 bit architecture, `i386`. Does anyone know how to do that?

I've already tried

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos=1.17.3:i386
sudo apt-get install tofrodos:i386=1.17.3
```

and none of them worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use the software center or aptitude to get the full version name. usually somethin like 1.17.3-ubuntu#

Answer (score 7):

Nobody can guarantee that the package in the repository will be a fixed version.

It is possible to hold an installed package from upgrading, but `apt` will always install an available version from the repos. Nobody keeps old versions there.

There actually may be two versions the initial one and an "upgrade" one.

But it is very unlikely that a package will be upgraded to some new major version in an LTS repository. Some minor fix may be released, but I don't think it can affect functionality.

The

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos:i386=version
```

is the correct command. But there is no `1.17.3` version in the repos.

The correct version is `1.7.13+ds-2ubuntu1`.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$apt-cache policy tofrodos
tofrodos:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.7.13+ds-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.7.13+ds-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

So the

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos:i386=1.7.13+ds-2ubuntu1
```

should work.

It is the "initial" version for `xenial`. Even if the package is upgraded in `xenial-updates` the command will install this version.

Answer (score 2):

If the package is available in the repositories you can install a specific version from a specific architecture of a package using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install package:i386=version
```

to see if your desired version is available to you, use:

```
apt-cache madison package-name
```

or

```
apt-cache policy package-name
```

the other option for your case is:

```
apt list -a i386 tofrodos
```

And it seems your desired package version does not exist in the repositories.

Comment: How can this work?

Comment: How can not? is something wrong with the package? cause I think the command is wrong ... !?

Comment: Ubuntu repos have one version of a package for each release. So it makes no sense to specify a version.

Comment: You sure? cause always a base version is available in the `dist` repository and the updates will be placed in the `dist-updates` so you should have at least one and in most cases two version, However as I can see the OP's command is wrong so I provide another command which I know works (If the package exists in repo).

Comment: Oh, you are correct. There are actually two versions.

Comment: @Ravexina It didn't work. I got the following error: `E: Command line option 'a' [from -a] is not understood in combination with the other options.`

Comment: @flashburn seems `-a` does not work along side the `install`, I updated the command, and the thing is your version is not available in the repository at all ...

Comment: @flashburn See my answer. It gives all the info.